# Why does the len() return a tuple in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

here is my code. And the strange thing is the quoted_product_num is tuple.

```
    def _compute_quotation_project(self):
        """
            The result should be a string with a pattern like 'A / B'
            A represents how many replies are received from vendors
            B represents how many quotations are sent to vendors
            And if A > 0, change the state to 'Completed'
        """
        for rec in self:
            quoted_product_num = len(rec.requisition_id.vendor_ids.filtered(
                lambda v: rec in v.projects and v.state == VendorLineEnum.QUOTED.value)),
            rec.quotation_project = "{} / {}".format(
                quoted_product_num,
                len(rec.requisition_id.vendor_ids.filtered(lambda v: rec in v.projects)),
            )
            # TODO Why quoted_product_num is a tuple?
            if quoted_product_num and rec.state == PurchaseReuqisitionLineStateEnum.IN_PROGRESS.value:
                rec.state = PurchaseReuqisitionLineStateEnum.COMPLETE.value
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the end of len(...) statement. That's creating a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a , before end of () which will create the tuple